# AWS Glue Crawler - Read a file with single column

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I would like to know if anyone had succeed in create use AWS Glue Crawler with a file with "single column".
This file has to be split by position and has no delimiter.

We tried to create a custom classifier with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this issue, we covered by creating a custom classifier with a proper regex to read it.

[image: AWS Crawler classifier]